# Differentiating the sum of an Arithmetic Progression.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives

Since Arithmetic Progression can be viewed as function of n , given by:

$$a_{n} = a+(n-1)D$$

So , like a normal function , we can use differentiation to find the rate of change of $a_n$ as :

$$\frac {d(a_n)}{dn} = \frac {d(a + (n-1)D)}{dn} = D$$

which gives the obvious answer : D (D is the common difference.)

But if we differentiate $S_n$ with respect to $n$ gives : 
$$\frac {d(S_n)}{dn} = \frac{d(\frac n2 (2a + (n-1)D))}{dn} = a+(n-\frac 12)D$$

Which implies $$\frac {d(S_n)}{dn} =  a+(n-\frac 12)D = \frac{a_n + a_{n+1}}{2}$$

My question is : **Why is the derivative of $S_n$ equals to the average of $a_n $ and $a_{n+1}$? Is there a much more elegant way to prove this?**

Also , Is using the the notion of calculus in A.P correct?

Comment: I guess you can use the notion of calculus in AP if you assume that $n$ is a real number. Calculus is applicable only when $n$ is continuous. Never forget the fundamental principle of differential calculus ^_^

Comment: Differentiation of the  sum is wrong.

Comment: @WilliamElliot How??

Comment: $S_n$ is defined only for $n\in\Bbb N$. $\frac{d(S_n)}{dn}$ is nonsensical. $\frac{d(\frac n2 (2a + (n-1)D))}{dn}$ makes sense as approximation, as @wgb22 suggests.

Answer (score 2):

With the arithmetic sequence, it is more suitable to consider:
$$\frac{\Delta S_n}{\Delta n}=\frac{S_{n+1}-S_n}{(n+1)-n}=a_{n+1}$$
Indeed, if $n$ increases by $1$, the sum $S_n$ increases by the next term $a_{n+1}$.

By taking derivative $\frac{dS_n}{dn}$, you are considering $n$ continuous, rather discrete. Hence:
$$\small{\frac{dS_n}{dn}=\left(\frac{a+a_n}{2}\cdot n\right)'=\frac{(a_n)'n+a+a_n}{2}=\frac{a_n+a+dn}{2}=\frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}.}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a finite differences approach since this is a discrete case, the sum is changing by the size of the terms. For $S_n$, it either increases by $a_{n+1} = a + nD$, or decreases by $a_{n} = a + (n-1)D$.

The centred finite difference is $\frac{\Delta S_n}{2}$, where $\Delta S_n = a_{n+1}+a_{n}$.

This formula so happens to be the average of $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$, which is predicted by the continuous approximation proposed in the question.